# Assign a 2d subset tensor with the sin/cos of itself periodically in TensorFlow.js

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

How to translate the following Python codes into TensorFlow.js?

```
# apply sin to even indices in the array; 2i
angle_rads[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])

# apply cos to odd indices in the array; 2i+1
angle_rads[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying sin to even indices and cos to odd indices indicates that we are filtering the initial tensor accross columns. to use tf.where, the first dimension must match the condition size meaning that tf.where will make a partition accross rows. Therefore, the initial tensor needs to be transposed.

```
const p = t.transpose()
```

The second step will be to create a tensor of condition from the initial tensor shape  last dimension `t.shape[t.shape.length -1]` - it becomes the permuted tensor first dimension `p.shape[0]`.

```
const cond = tf.tensor1d(Array.from({length: p.shape[0]},(_, i) => i%2 === 1), 'bool')
```

tensors are immutable. it is not possible to reassign to the initial tensor. When the tensor values are modified, a new tensor is created.

Everything together:

```
const t = tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

p = t.transpose()
const cond = tf.tensor1d(Array.from({length: p.shape[0]}, 
                                       (_, i) => i%2 === 1), 'bool')
const newp = p.cos().where(cond, p.sin());
const newt = newp.transpose()
newt.print()
```